# HTML table with javascript popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, popupwindow

I've been trying to replicate [this](http://i.minus.com/jbgtAF6eRWaj0E.jpg).

But I keep hitting a bump while trying to make it so that if the picture is clicked on, a popup with a fixed width appears;

This is my popup script;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('HTTPLINK');">Description</a>
```

I'm trying to get this done while using basic HTML tables.  Any ideas on how to get this done? If you have a better procedure on how to achieve this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will want something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>

<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('HTTPLINK');"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jbgtAF6eRWaj0E.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! Now could you please tell me how to get them into a table? I would like 3 small pictures (about 150x150) in one row and ten the next and so on...